# PHP Photo Polarizing Filter Classes Direction?

Tags: php, image, imagemagick

I'm looking for the simplest way to add a polarizing effects to user uploaded photos through forms.

Should I be looking for something other than ImageMagick(MagickWand)?

Anything out of the box option out there or this should be a custom build?

Comment: You cannot properly apply the effects of a polarizing filter except by using such a filter when taking the photo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to simulate polarizing effect in Photoshop.
One of the steps needs a different solution in imagemagic/gd-library (masking reds).
photoshoptutorials.ws/photoshop-tutorials/photo-effects/polarizing-filter.html

Could you instead be thinking about a solarizing effect?

This class has "solarizeImage(int $threshold)"
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php